# Intermittent Issues Opening websocket on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sockets, websocket, amazon-ecs

Running my Golang app using gorilla websockets in AWS ECS using Fargate and an ALB in front. A couple days ago connecting to the socket was working and then would intermittently fail. Now it is consistently failing to open the socket.

I've tried connecting through the ALB with and without the port as well as connecting to the public ip the ECS Task is running on.

The error my app is logging:
websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header

Here are the headers that my app receives. The connection header is somehow missing by the time my app handles the request

`{ "Sec-Websocket-Extensions": [ "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits" ], "Sec-Websocket-Key": [ "q3QD34m6Qx2BKPYQJCPACA==" ], "Sec-Websocket-Protocol": [ "websocket" ], "Sec-Websocket-Version": [ "13" ], "Userid": [ "abc123" ], "Via": [ "1.1 ::ffff:172.20.32.1 (Mikrotik HttpProxy)" ], "X-Forwarded-Port": [ "80" ], "X-Forwarded-Proto": [ "http" ], "X-Proxy-Id": [ "619378727" ] }`

Ways I've tried to connect:

`wscat -nc ws://www.example.com/v1/ws`

`wscat -nc ws://www.example.com:80/v1/ws`

`wscat -nc ws://<public ip>/v1/ws`

`wscat -nc ws://<public ip>:80/v1/ws`